# Smallest $n$ where $2 \cdot \sum_{k = 1}^{n} \frac{\left(\frac{n}{100}\right)^k}{k!} \geq e^{\frac{n}{100}}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, stochastic-calculus, poisson-distribution

I'm having a problem with solving the following relation for $n$:

$$2 \cdot \sum_{k = 1}^{n} \dfrac{\left(\frac{n}{100}\right)^k}{k!} \geq e^{\frac{n}{100}}$$

By trial-and-error I was already able to confirm, that $n \geq 70$ but I have yet to show it mathematically. I somehow cannot find a way to get rid of the summation, which looks a lot like the exponential function for $e^{\frac{n}{100}}$.

I transformed this relation from the following task:

A randomly chosen person has blood type AB- with a probability of about 1%. How many persons have to be chosen at least, so that there is at least one person with blood type AB- with a probability of at least 50%. (You may use a suitable approximation.)

Choosing poisson distribution, I came up with:
$$\sum_{k = 1}^{n} \mathcal{P}_{\lambda = \left(n \cdot \frac{1}{100}\right)} \left(\left\lbrace k \right\rbrace\right)= \sum_{k = 1}^{n} e^{-\left(n\cdot\frac{1}{100}\right)} \cdot \dfrac{\left(n\cdot\frac{1}{100}\right)^k}{k!} \geq \dfrac{1}{2}$$

Comment: Without answering your question: are you sure that the choice of a Poisson distribution is a good one? Usually one chooses it for events that happen in (discrete) time, whereas there is no time flow in your problem. To me blood type seems uniformly distributed in a population and a uniform distribution is what I would use.

Comment: From what I learned one can use a Poisson distribution to approximate a binomial distribution whenever $n$ is big enough and $p$ is small enough (so at least $n \geq 50$ and $p \leq 0,05$)

Comment: This is hardly a justification. The introduction of the Wikipedia [article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_distribution) on this theme might give you some hints, together with the [rest](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_distribution#Occurrence) of the article. Usually this distribution is used when studying events happening in some time interval, or in some space interval, or age interval etc. Usually it is something about "intervals", which is not the case in your problem. I do not know for sure, but as I have said, I think that you should use a uniform distribution.

Comment: This what our docent has taught us. And actually if you're calculating with $n=70$ and try both, binomial distribution as well as Poisson distribution, you will notice that the result will be about the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I was able to come up with a fairly simple answer.

Instead of finding an $n$, so that $1, 2, \ldots, n$ people have have blood type AB- and are amongst the chosen group of people with a probability of at least 50%, it is easier to find an $n$, so that the probability of $0$ people having blood type AB- is at most 50%:
\begin{alignat*}{2}
 \mathcal{P}_{\lambda = \left(n \cdot \frac{1}{100}\right)} \left(\left\lbrace 0 \right\rbrace\right) = \ & e^{-\frac{n}{100}} \cdot \underbrace{\dfrac{\left(\frac{n}{100}\right)^0}{0!}}_{= 1} &&\leq \dfrac{1}{2}\\
 \Leftrightarrow \ & e^{-\frac{n}{100}} &&\leq \dfrac{1}{2}\\
 \Leftrightarrow \ & -\frac{n}{100} &&\leq \ln\left(\dfrac{1}{2}\right)\\
 \Leftrightarrow \ & n &&\geq -100 \cdot \ln\left(\dfrac{1}{2}\right)\\
 \Leftrightarrow \ & n &&\geq 100 \cdot \ln\left(2\right)\\
 \Rightarrow \ & n &&= \lceil 100 \cdot \ln\left(2\right) \rceil = 70
\end{alignat*}
As @Travis has already mentioned in a comment, $n$ is indeed $100 \cdot \ln\left(2\right)$.

@Alex M. raised the question, whether the obviously binomial distributed problem could even be approximated by Poisson distribution:
\begin{alignat*}{3}
& \mathcal{B}_{\left(70, \frac{1}{100}\right)}\left(\left\lbrace 0 \right\rbrace \right)  &&= \begin{pmatrix} 70 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix} \cdot \left(\dfrac{1}{100}\right)^0 \cdot \left(\dfrac{99}{100}\right)^{70} &&\approx 0.4948\\
& \mathcal{P}_{\lambda = \left(\frac{70}{100}\right)} \left(\left\lbrace 0 \right\rbrace\right) &&= e^{-\frac{70}{100}} \cdot \dfrac{\left(\frac{70}{100}\right)^0}{0!} &&\approx 0.4966\\
& \sum_{k = 1}^{70} \mathcal{B}_{\left(70, \frac{1}{100}\right)}\left(\left\lbrace k \right\rbrace \right) &&= \sum_{k = 1}^{70} \begin{pmatrix} 70 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix} \cdot \left(\dfrac{1}{100}\right)^k \cdot \left(\dfrac{99}{100}\right)^{70-k} &&\approx 0.5052\\
& \sum_{k = 1}^{70} \mathcal{P}_{\lambda = \left(\frac{70}{100}\right)} \left(\left\lbrace k \right\rbrace\right) &&= \sum_{k = 1}^{70} e^{-\frac{70}{100}} \cdot \dfrac{\left(\frac{70}{100}\right)^k}{k!} &&\approx 0.5034\\
\end{alignat*}
One could indeed find, that $n \geq 69$ is a little more exact, when using the binomial distribution. But Poisson distribution is still a very precise approximation.

Answer (score 2):

for your equation i have found
$$2\,{\frac {1}{\Gamma  \left( n+1 \right) }{{\rm e}^{{\frac {n}{100}}}}
\Gamma  \left( n+1,{\frac {n}{100}} \right) }-2-{{\rm e}^{{\frac {n}{
100}}}}=0
$$
and a solution is $\approx 69,31471806$

Comment: was just about to write something similar ... (+1)

Comment: NB this number is $\sim 100 \log 2$.

Comment: Is there a way to show this without use of the gamma function? Sadly, we were never taught this particular function.

Comment: oh thats very good if its true

Comment: This cannot even qualify as an answer. In the best case the author *may* be awarded some prize about knowing how to use Mathematica.

Comment: @AlexM. Sometimes you really just need to find a number, and computational methods are a part of mathematics.

Comment: @Joel: And in this case, trying out all the natural numbers up to $70$ is yet another legitimate approach, but the OP makes it clear that he also wants some understanding of the underlying facts, not just a number.